# family of functions/sequences taken over reals instead of naturals

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, convolution, uniform-convergence

How does convergence for a sequence and
a family of functions change when considering $n$ taken from $\mathbb{R}$ instead 
of the $\mathbb{N}$? for example, consider mollifiers which are defined as follows:

If $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is locally integrable, define its mollification $$f^{\epsilon} := \eta_{\epsilon}*f \text{ in } U_{\epsilon}$$

That is, $f^{\epsilon}(x) = \int_{U} \eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)dy = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(y)f(x-y)dy$

for $x \in U_{\epsilon}$

are defined it is given that it has properties such as $f^{\epsilon} \rightarrow f  \text{ a.e  as } \epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $f^{\epsilon} \rightarrow  f$ uniformly
on compact sets if $f$ is continuous on the domain. Are these definitions of point-wise convergence and uniform convergence the  same as for the countable family of functions usually given as $(f_{n})_{n}$ 
with $n$ taken from the natural numbers? What about sequences $(x_{n})_{n}$ taken over
$\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$?

By the way these definitions and properties of mollifiers are from the book 'partial differential equations' by Lawrence C.Evans.

Comment: Off the bat, the first thing to try is to see whether or not the subsequence $f^{1/n}$ is cofinal in this sequence. If so, then convergence *should* be the same as with $\Bbb N$-sequences.

Comment: Well for example $x_n=\tan(n\pi)$ if we take that $n\in \mathbb{R}$ things pretty much completely change,though I'm not really sure if this is what you've asked for

Comment: @kingW3 To an extent, but I was asking more generally what changes in terms of applying definitions and theorems.

Answer (score 0):

To define convergence, we specify traps and tails. The definition   always* says the same thing: *convergence happens if every trap catches [i.e., contains] some tail*. Traps and tails can be indexed by however you want to index them; some examples are given below.

#### Traps (for convergence to $f$):

- Uniform convergence: $T_\epsilon = \{g : |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \text{ for all $x$}\}$
- Pointwise convergence: $T_{x,\epsilon} = \{g : |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\}$
- Convergence in $L^p$ norm: $T_\epsilon = \{g : \|g -f \|_{L^p}<\epsilon  \}$
- Convergence in measure: $T_{\epsilon,\delta} = \{g : \mu(\{x : |g (x)-f(x)  |\ge \delta\}) <\epsilon  \}$

#### Tails

- for a sequence:  $t_N = \{f_n : n\ge  N\}$
- for a family indexed by   a positive number:  $t_\delta = \{f^\epsilon : \epsilon <\delta \}$
- for a [net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29), $t_\alpha = \{f_\beta : \beta\succeq \alpha\}$

To directly address your question:

> Are these definitions of point-wise convergence and uniform convergence the same as for the countable family of functions?

The traps are the same, the tails are different (see above).

---

(*) A notable exception to the above is *[convergence almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9063)*, which does not fit into any topology. You are unlikely to see  "$f^\epsilon \to f$ almost everywhere as $\epsilon\to 0$"; although this convergence *could* be defined for uncountable families, it is not natural for them.

Comment: @user147039 Why is convergence almost everywhere a notable exception? Can we not follow the same 'trap' and 'tail' concept that you described above?