# Examples of "non-topological" convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for some interesting examples of [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space) (or related notions), which use a convergence that doesn't come from a topology.

I know about "convergence-almost-everywhere". What other examples are there?

---

EDIT: It seems my question is more or less a duplicate of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5537/notions-of-convergence-not-corresponding-to-topologies) question on mathoverflow.

Comment: Not really sure what you're looking for. Your example of a.e. convergence still seems topological to me. All notions of convergence that I can think of are phrase in terms of a topology.

Comment: @rschwieb http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/characterization-of-almost-everywhere-convergence

Comment: I think the convergence almost everywhere example can be generalised by the following example: suppose we have a topological space $X$ with an equivalence relation $E$. We say that a sequence $x_n$ converges mod $E$ if there is a sequence $x_n'$ with $x_n\mathrel{E} x_n'$ such that $x_n'$ converges. This is similar, but apparently not equivalent to convergence in quotient topology on $X/E$. If you take for $X$ the space of measurable functions with pointwise convergence and for $E$ equality almost everywhere, you obtain convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: @StefanPerko I think you might have drawn the wrong conclusion. That the functions can't be topologized to give a.e. convergence does not mean it is not topological. As far as I can see, a.e. convergence is just convergence in the metric space of *equivalence classes* of functions. (The equivalence relation being that two functions are a.e. equal.)

Comment: @rschwieb: Now you got me curious. So what do you think it would mean that a.e. convergence is not topological?

Comment: @tomasz I don't follow the linked post exactly, but what I think it shows is that a.e. convergence does not arise from a topology on *the functions themselves*, which makes sense, given that the convergence does not have suitable properties *for functions*.

Comment: @rschwieb: That seems right. But that sounds like exatly the kind of example OP is asking about (and he seems to agree, since that's the example he provided!). I was just curious about what other notion of "non-topogical convergence" you had in mind.

Comment: @tomasz Well, I'm open to virtually any kind of example. They don't need to be similar or even remotely related to the one I specified. E.g. one answer in the MO question linked briefly touched upon "alternative summation methods" (Cesaro et al), which sounded interesting.

Comment: @tomasz I'll just leave things as they are: looks like the linked question is a big help to understanding what the intent of this question is.

Comment: The Q makes me think of Iterated Forcing constructions. Although they are not called convergent. But in practice, they have properties that are  analogous to convergence.

Answer (score 2):

In "Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations" one can find a vast (and arguably interesting and useful!) generalization of the "convergence almost everywhere":

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a complete lattice (this works for general posets too, but the definitions are considerably more cumbersome):

Given a net $(x_n)_{n\in A}$ in $P$ define:

$$\liminf_{n\in A} x_n = \bigvee_{n\in A} \bigwedge_{m\geq n} x_m,\,\limsup_{n\in A} x_n = \bigwedge_{n\in A} \bigvee_{m\geq n} x_m$$

We say $(x_n)_{n\to A}$ *order converges* to $\tilde x$, if $\liminf_{x\in A} x_n = \tilde x = \limsup_{x\in A}$.

(with a bit of work one can recast the definition in terms of a filters and verify the axioms of a convergence space).

The "convergence almost everywhere"-structure tells us, that this convergence structure need not be topological: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Define $P$ to be the set of measurable functions $\Omega \to [-\infty\,..\infty]$ modulo equality $\mu$-a.e. and let $f\leq g$, if $f$ is smaller then $g$ $\mu$-a.e. Then $(P,\leq)$ is a complete lattice (using "essential suprema" and "essential infima") and order convergence and convergence $\mu$-a.e. coincide, but the latter is not topological.

Comment: For example: there is (or was 50 years ago) some study of "vector lattices", vector spaces, also lattices, with compatability between the two structures.  "Convergence" defined as limsup=liminf is convenient there, but adding a topology may not be.

Comment: @GEdgar That seems interesting. Do you happen to know an important example of a vector lattice (besides an $L^p$ space) where order convergence is not topological? If so, feel free to write an answer with some details, if you like.