# Can I find the topology according to certain definition of convergence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces

For instance, consider the space $C[0,1]$, I hope $f_n \rightarrow f$ means that $\sup_{[0,1]} |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$.

I know the convergence is meaningful only by specifying the topology, and I am wondering whether I induce one topology by the specified convergence.

Comment: Hint: think about metric spaces first (and maybe the real analysis course)

Comment: If I know it's a metric space, I'v know the open set.

Comment: This is possible in general, but the axioms are quite involved and you need to use nets rather than sequences, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19285/how-do-you-axiomatize-topology-via-nets).

Comment: @Thorgott, actually it seems that you can just use [sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/when-is-a-notion-of-convergence-induced-by-a-topology?rq=1), but the axioms are still pretty involved.

Comment: @Alessandro I've not checked the details of that, but it seems to describe only sequential spaces (in the first place, it is not possible to completely describe non-sequential spaces only using sequences, pretty much by definition). But I guess this is more appropriate for OP who seems to start with a notion of convergence and wants a topology realizing this notion. All my remark adds is that not all topological spaces can be described that way.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't really need the notion of topology to make sense of the notion of convergence. In fact, there are notions of convergence that are provably [not-topological](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075916/examples-of-non-topological-convergence) (like convergence almost everywhere). Non-topological notions of convergence arise naturally, so one may be lead to consider new notions of space, like [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space), where convergence is primitive (as opposed to being induced by something else, like a topology). You might wanna take a look at the article [An initiation into convergence theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228377390_An_initiation_into_convergence_theory). In the article the author also describes how a convergence space induces a topology on the underlying set, the problem is that then this topology will introduce a (possibly strictly) weaker notion of convergence than the one you started with (for example, read [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5537/notions-of-convergence-not-corresponding-to-topologies)).