# A topology $\tau$ on $ L([0,1])$ that induces the $almost-everywhere$ convergence on $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, pointwise-convergence, almost-everywhere

*Let be $L([0,1])$ the vector space of equivalence classes of measurable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$* (I don't have more details about the type of equivalence that the exercise is talking abut, I guess it's this one: $[f]=\{g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ | g=f \ almost \ everywhere \ in \ [0,1]\}$). $$$$
*Prove that:
$\nexists \tau$ topology  on  $ L([0,1])$ that induces the $almost-everywhere$ convergence on  $[0,1]$* $$$$
I don't have further details about what this means, I guess that if a sequence of equivalence class of functions $\{[f]_n\}\subset L([0,1])$ converge to a class of function $[f]\in L([0,1])$ then $f_n$ should converges to $f$ almost-everywhere on $[0,1]$.
I wanted to prove this by absurd, creating a sequence of function that converges in $L([0,1])$ but not $almost-everywhre$ on $[0,1]$, any help?

Comment: http://ordman.net/MathResearch/1966A.pdf

Comment: I found this one:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/characterization-of-almost-everywhere-convergence
But I can't comprehend the last part of the proof, how did he prove that $f_n$ doesn't converge a.e. in $0$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The Borel-Cantelli part?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't undertand that part

Comment: Honestly, not sure - it's been some time. Apparently, the second Borel-Cantelli lemma is being used here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), but it seems to required at least pairwise independence

Comment: But also, don't mind it. This sequence does not converge a.e. since for *every* $x$ you will have $f_n(x) = 1$ for sufficiently big $n$ over and over again. I hope, this part is clear

Comment: Let me understand if I understood: because for every $x\in [0,1]$ I can find a sub-sequence of ${f_n}$ such that for every $n\geq1:$ $f_n(x)=1$, so the set in which ${f_n}$ converges in $0$ is neglibile, right?

Comment: So there’s no point in which $f_n$ converges